# Rotator stops working when using  replace

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with our website. I am trying to replace all occurrences of one phone number with different one.

If you go to [www.paintballgames.co.uk](http://www.paintballgames.co.uk) you will see the regular page

If you go to [www.paintballgames.co.uk/?test=phtest](http://www.paintballgames.co.uk/?test=phtest) you will see one with changed number

However the rotator is not working in the second case.

I tried to compare source codes and only difference was, that in second case, I had some code that is changing the code displayed.

The code I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = document.getElementById('forChange').innerHTML;
    str = str.replace("844 477 5050", "844 477 5178");
    document.getElementById('forChange').innerHTML = str;
</script>
```

Anyone can share any light on that?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I see an exception with javascript even on the regular site:

```
$("#container-inline").html("<input type="image" name="op" value="GO" id="search-form-submit"  class="form-image" />");
```

This will not work, as you should either escape quotes or use single quotes:

```
$("#container-inline").html("<input type=\"image\" name=\"op\" value=\"GO\" id=\"search-form-submit\"  class=\"form-image\" />");
```

or

```
$("#container-inline").html("<input type='image' name='op' value='GO' id='search-form-submit'  class='form-image' />");
```

**UPDATE:**
And one more exception in "click_heatmap.js":

```
Drupal.behaviors.click_heatmap = function()) { 
// the "function()) {" is invalid. It should be "function() {"
click_heatmap.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
  if (window.location.href != parent.location.href) {
    $('#admin-menu').remove();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
It is possible, that after fixing the errors, you'll see the root of the problem.

**UPDATE 3:**
Why at all you are changing the phone number in Javascript and not on your server side?

**UPDATE 4:**
Now I've got even more interesting things! The 'forChange' element is almost the whole site wrapper! You should never write such code!
Instead of that you should have done this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("SPAN.phone-now").text("your text"); 
});
```

**UPDATE 5:**
Now I can explain, why Javascript stops working. When you write something like `body.innerHtml = body.innerHtml.replace(...)` ALL the Javascript, which was there gets lost and the new one is not executed. So, nothing works! All references, which were saved in Javascript they point to not visible "old" elements.

Comment: Now I can explain, why Javascript stops working. When you write something like `body.innerHtml = body.innerHtml.replace(...)` ALL the Javascript, which was there gets lost and the new one is not executed. So, nothing works! All references, which were saved in Javascript they point to not visible "old" elements.

Comment: You should add your comment to the answer, I think it's the most important information.

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot. Here are answers to few of your questions. It is Drupal website, so it is hard to control output of some modules. We want to use unique number to track PPC calls. Therefore, if you come from PPC advert, we want to show different number. Alexander, your code works perfectly. Thanks. One thing - it doesnt change all numbers on the page. Any suggestion how to change one at the bottom? i tried  $("DIV.footer-left-top").text("0844 477 5178"); but it doesnt work. thanks,

Comment: got it. i just added <span class="phone-now"> around the number =)